# How to handle visibility of div only by clicking of particular div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have 4 div all div consist of images.
Position of all the div's are like top left div, top right div, bottom left div and bottom right div.
and I have one more div which is in the panel control in the center, which will disable by default.

When I click any of the div (top left div, top right div, bottom left div and bottom right div) all this four div should be disabled and visibility should be false.

and div that we have clicked that should be shown in the center div which is in the panel.

Is it possible to perform by using div clicking.

and one more thing I do not have any button control.

I want to handle all this by only clicking of div.

CODE

```
     <div class="img_top" style="margin-top: 40%">
                    <div class="img_top_left">
                        dgsdfg</div>
                    <div class="img_top_right">
                        dfgdsfg</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img_bottom" style="margin-top: 60%">
                    <div class="img_bottom_left">
                        dgsdfg</div>
                    <div class="img_bottom_right">
                        dfgdsfg</div>
                </div>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <div class="img_center">
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

CSS

```
.img_center
{
    margin-top:50%;
     height:250px;
     background-color:Green;
}
.img_top_left
{
    height:250px;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    background-color:Blue;
}
.img_bottom_right
{
     height:250px;
    margin-left:20%;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    background-color:Orange;
}
.img_bottom_left
{
    height:250px;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    background-color:Blue;
}
.img_top_right
{
     height:250px;
    margin-left:20%;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    background-color:Orange;
}
```

Comment: You can assign a handler to a `click` event on a `div`: `$('div#someID').click(someFunction);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jquery you could do something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#toprightcenter').hide();
            $('#topleftcenter').hide();
            $('#bottomrightcenter').hide();
            $('#bottomleftcenter').hide();

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#topright').click(function() {
            $('#topright').hide();
            $('#topleft').hide();
            $('#bottomright').hide();
            $('#bottomleft').hide();
            $('#toprightcenter').toggle();
 return false;
});
```

This should hide the central divs when the page loads and should then hide the other divs when clicking on the top right div and should show the toprightcenter div.

For this to work you will obviously have to make some center divs that hold the content from all the four corners and name it something like #toprightcenter and then another and name it #topleftcenter etc.

Then repeat the function above swapping topright for topleft in the click function area at the top and so on until you have a code block for each sequence of events you need.

Hope that helps or gets you some way there.

Answer (score 1):

You're more likely to do this using jQuery instead of ASP.NET

Try this:

```
$('div').click(function () { // all divs
  $('div').hide(); // hide all the divs
  var divId = $(this).attr('id'); // get the id of the div
  /* use the css properties to position it at the center, for example */
  $(this).css({
    'margin', '10px' /* add more as required */
  });
}
```

You can use the CSS properties to change the position of the element, and all the other elements will still be there! So, you need to use:

```
#div {
  position: absolute;
}
```

In this way, you can change the position of the element relative to the other elements. You can add this property via jQuery too, using the `.css()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your divs have id's

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id')
    if(thisId == 'topleft' || thisId == 'topright' || thisId == 'bottomleft' || thisId == 'bottomright') {
        $(this).hide()
        $('#centrediv').html('<p>' + thisId + '</p>')
    };
});
```